# Strange malloc crashing issues

Tags: c, pointers, dictionary

`dict[num] = malloc(INIT);`

`assert(dict != NULL);`

Where dict is a `char**` , and INIT is 10 [at the time of crash, dict** has 80 memory realloced to it, which should be enough for around 20 strings], num is 15 during the crash

I have a strange situation with malloc where

`malloc(25)` = entire function runs fine

`malloc(17-24)` = assertion error - line 2

`malloc(anything <=16)` = crashes on line 1

If it helps, `dict[num]` is supposed to hold 2 chars, a letter (or newline), a number, and a nullbyte. `dict[15]` happens to be  '\n0'.

Why is this happening? I thought you only need to allocate as much memory as there are characters.

For the record I also have a `memset(dict[num],'\0',INIT)` line that occurs after the malloc + assert lines.

EDIT = here's the entire function - it's supposed to be a LZ78 compressor/encoder

```
char *factory(char *input,int max){
int j,k,match,subtractor=0;
char *x = malloc(INIT);

char **dict = malloc(10*sizeof(dict[0]));
int dict_size = INIT;
assert ( dict != NULL );

char *temp = malloc(INIT);
int temp_size = INIT;
assert ( temp != NULL );

char *factors = malloc(INIT);
assert ( factors != NULL );
char *tempstring = malloc(INIT);
int tempstr_size = INIT;
assert ( tempstring != NULL );

int dlen = 1;

int dmax = 1;
factor_t *factorstr = malloc(INIT);
int break2 = 0;
memset(dict,'\0',INIT);
dict[0] = "";
x = input;

char unmatched[2];
unmatched[1] = '\0';
while(strlen(x)){
    match = 0;
    memset(temp,'\0',temp_size);
    if (dlen>INIT){
        temp_size = temp_size + dlen;
        temp = realloc( temp, temp_size );
        assert( temp != NULL );
    }
    printf("DMAX = %d\n",dmax);
    if (dmax==dict_size){
        dict_size *= 2;
        dict = realloc(dict, dict_size*sizeof(*dict));
        assert(dict != NULL);
    }

    for(j=0;j<dlen;j++){
        if (dlen > strlen(x)){
            dlen = strlen(x) - 1;
            printf("\nRunning out of space! DLEN = %d\n",dlen);
        }
        memset(temp,'\0',temp_size);
        strncpy(temp, &x[0], dlen-j);

        for(k=0;k<dmax;k++){
            if (strcmp(temp,dict[k])==0){
                if ((strlen(temp)+1)>(tempstr_size)){
                    tempstr_size += strlen(temp) + 1;
                    tempstring = realloc( tempstring , tempstr_size);
                    assert( tempstring != NULL );
                }
                unmatched[0] = x[dlen-j];
                memset(tempstring, '\0', tempstr_size);
                strcat(tempstring,temp);
                strcat(tempstring,unmatched);
                dict[dmax] = malloc(strlen(tempstring)+100);
                assert ( dict[dmax] != NULL ) ;
                strcpy(dict[dmax], tempstring);
                dmax++;
                match = 1;
                subtractor = dlen-j;
                if (!j){
                    dlen++;
                }
                break2 = 1;
                break;
            }
            }
            if (break2){
                break2=0;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (!match){
        unmatched[0] = x[0];

        factorstr[dmax].c = unmatched[0];
        factorstr[dmax].k = 0;

        dict[dmax] = malloc(INIT);
        assert ( dict[dmax] != NULL );

        memset(dict[dmax],'\0',INIT);
        strcpy(dict[dmax],unmatched);
        printf("dict dmax = %s\n",dict[dmax]);
        dmax++;
        subtractor = 1;
    }
    x = x + subtractor;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Could you paste up an sscce please?

Comment: what's an sscce? num is 15 as mentioned in the post

Comment: [A short, self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/). It is much easier and reliable to read code than your verbal descriptions. If the code is long, try to isolate the behavour in a shorter code snipped and post that.

Comment: You have allocated space for `dict` itself?

Comment: How do you allocate `char **dict`?

Comment: What is the size of the dict array? Somewhere you had to give it a fixed size (i.e. char *dict[100] for example. If you specify an index that is outside this boundary, you are going to get run time errors (i.e. num is 101).

Comment: You wrote `malloc(17-24)`. I'm no expert on memory but at first sight that looks like allocating negative memory which can't be possible

Comment: @Arc676 I think he  meant the range of indexes 17-24

Comment: Yeah, I meant range of indexes - i tried malloc(17), malloc(18), etc

Comment: By the way, the [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) *macro* is only doing something in debug builds. If you are doing a release build (where `NDEBUG` is defined) then `assert` does nothing. Don't use `assert` as a way to check for success/failure. Besides, if an assert fails the program will abort immediately, which might not be correct all the time.

Comment: `dict[15]`, yet it only holds space for 10 pointers to char, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: As for your problem, you should probably run in a debugger to catch the crashes/aborts, and check the sizes of the allocated memory and make sure that the index is withing range.

Comment: When you call the functions that take raw data, such as ´malloc` and `memset`, the size must be given in bytes. That usually means `count * sizeof(*handle)`. You can leave out the `sizeof` part when you are dealing with chars.

Comment: You do `x = malloc(INIT)` and later, just before the loop, you assign `x = input`, thereby losing the handle to the allocated memory.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand - What does that mean? if `x = malloc(INIT)` and I do `x=input` does that mean all the memory is lost? Or that the memory that x points is no longer assigned to X?

Comment: `malloc` returns a handle to the memory. You should hold on to that handle until you release the memory again with `free`. By overwriting this handle, you lose it and cannot free it later. This is called a memory leak. (Think of the allocated memory as an array. You can't re-assign an array either.)

Comment: I replaced all instances of x with input, do I need to malloc input even though it's an argument to the function `factory`? It's basically a long string/1d array to be processed

Comment: In your function, you only read from `x`/`input`. That is you use memory that is already there; it was provided by the calling function. `malloc` is for new memory, for example if you want to copy something there. Make the `input` a `const char *`, so that your code can't overwrite and change it and don't allocate. The allocations for `dict` and `temp` are in order, though.

Comment: You also need to allocate `factor_t *factorstr = malloc(INIT * sizeof(*factorstr));`.

Comment: My func works by deleting text that isn't used via `x = x + subtractor` where `subtractor` is the amount of text i've processed - so I don't think I can use const char*, because I need to modify the contents, don't I?

Comment: `const char *x` means you can't change what `x` points to, but you can change `x` itself.  What you mean is `char *const x`. Here, you can change the contents of `x`, but not the pointer itself. You never write to the input string, but you advance the pointer, so `const char *x` is good.

Answer (score 2):

```
memset(dict,'\0',INIT);
```

This is a bug and doesn't make any sense. `dict` is a pointer to an array of pointers. It is not a string and it does not have size `INIT`.